# Creating SSRS style expressions (functions) in a .Net server application

Tags: c#, .net, function, transform, expression

We have a rather flexible application written in C# (.net 4.0) that copies data to different ERP systems around the company.  It uses an XML file to determine the from and to ERP systems, the data source, credentials, and the columns to copy.

What we are seeing is that the is an interest in transforming the data as it is copied.  So a part number with a product family, gets converted to just a product family.  For example to do the following transformation 564-8911277 ==> 564 using SSRS functions this would be

```
=Left("564-8911277", instr(564-8911277", "-") - 1))
```

The thought is to put the expression in the XML file and have the system interpret the expression and transform the data.

I'm researching and working on a cost estimate to develop this feature, and wondering if there is anything out there that already exists that can be integrated into a .net application?

I've found a few things (scripting.net from 2001), but thought I'd reach out to the community to see what else is out there.

Thanks, Tim

Comment: I wrote something a while ago: https://github.com/taspeotis/ExpressionEvaluator

Comment: Thanks @ta.speot.is I'll take a look at this.  I also found a [Calculation Engine for .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246374/A-Calculation-Engine-for-NET) on Codeproject